# using php and mysql, insert timestamp on user logout

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL

When a user logs in I am able to insert their log-in time-stamp into MySQL while using sessions and with the use of a function. The function would update the database and works wonderfully.

Now, is it possible to get a time-stamp and have it recorded into MySQL the same way when the user clicks on "log-out" and where the log-out will run `session_destroy()`?

All I am looking for is a time stamp of when the user clicks on log-out, just so I know they have been log-out. I not worried if they just closed the browser and walked away.

I have tried doing something like session_destroy(something); and using this as function. All I got was run-time errors. Is this something that is even possible to do?

Comment: no, I'm afraid there is no way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287064/php-session-timeout-callback had some good ideas

Answer (score 2):

You should have no problem recording a logout time when a user clicks logout (of course this won't work if the browser is closed).  Just get the UserID and update that user in the database before calling session_destroy().

For example:

Logout.php

```
$query = "update user set logoutDate=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where user={$_SESSION['userID']}";
mysql_query($query);

session_destroy();
```

Comment: Correct, but you should escape your input or use prepared statements. Also, the `mysql_` functions have begun the deprecation process. (Upvoted regardless.)

Comment: Thanks I have used: an include statement that calls my database. Then I done a session_start(); mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `logout` = NOW() WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[user_id]'"); session_destroy(); and done a header file. I have put this in a logout page. Hope this is a correct way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you Adam for pointing me in the wright direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
//code for inserting logout time in database of user
session_destroy();
```

and post your code also.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function called logout() similar to login(), except that it stores the logout timestamp and then calls session_destroy().

Comment: I like this idea, it keeps my pages a lot cleaner by using a logout function. This way I can keep all my functions in one spot. Thank you